How to insulate previosly enclosed front porch
My home is frome 1915, and the front and back porches were later enclosed, but they don't have full framing and insulation, just windows plus boards put up where the porch openings had been. What had previously been wood siding is now interior wall. What's the best way to go about framing and insulating these spaces? Should I remove the siding, or put new studs over it? I'll be removing the internal window and turning that into a French door. The back wall is the most irregular, and I don't quite understanding what is going on with the pillar in the corner.
https://imgur.com/a/R1fAkU1

It's not a great picture for us "net people" to determine what you are working with.  In a pinch I would say, remove whatever the sheathing is that is covering the inside of the  exterior porch wall. Instal Batt insulation and new covering on the walls.

It is usually better to work from the inside out, instead of from the outside.  Pouring rain will not get inside and everything stays dry.  Siding that is bad and needs to be replaced and a nice finish inside does make working from the outside a better choice.  So a new inside or a new outside is your choice.
